# Testlink and Bugzilla integration

Tags: report, integration, bugzilla, testlink

After the complete setup of Testlink and Bugzilla, I configured testlink to work with Bugzilla with this file config:

```
<issuetracker>
    <dbhost>localhost</dbhost>
    <dbname>bug</dbname>
    <dbschema>bug</dbschema>
    <dbtype>mysql</dbtype>
    <dbuser>bugzilla</dbuser>
    <dbpassword>bugzilla</dbpassword>
    <uricreate>http://localhost/bugzilla/</uricreate>
    <uriview>http://localhost/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=</uriview>
</issuetracker>
```

I tested the configuration and got a success response message. Now I want to generate report for test cases executed in Bugzilla.

[image]

When I click the save button to push the report to Bugzilla I got these errors:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Uri_Exception: Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\third_party\Zend\Uri.php:111 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\third_party\Zend\Http\Client.php(305): Zend_Uri::factory(Array) #1 
C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\third_party\Zend\XmlRpc\Client.php(266): Zend_Http_Client->setUri('/xmlrpc.cgi') #2 
C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\third_party\Zend\XmlRpc\Client.php(372): Zend_XmlRpc_Client->doRequest(Object(Zend_XmlRpc_Request)) #3 
C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\third_party\Zend\XmlRpc\Client\ServerProxy.php(93): Zend_XmlRpc_Client->call('system.methodSi...', Array) #4 
C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\third_party\Zend\XmlRpc\Client\ServerIntrospection.php(146): Zend_XmlRpc_Client_ServerProxy->__call('system.methodSi...', Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\third_party\Zend\XmlRpc\Client.php(315): Zend_XmlRpc_Client_ServerIntrospection->getMethodSignature('User.login') #6 
C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\lib\issuetrackerintegration\bugzillaxmlrpcInterface.class.php(451): in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\third_party\Zend\Uri.php on line 111
```

What's the solution to this?